# How to redirect after auth in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When I authorize in Laravel 5.3 I redirect to `/home` page.

I tried to change this on: `protected $redirectTo = '/order';` in file `LoginController`.

But It does not work, I am redirected on home still.

Comment: Do you go to '/home' after logging in, or only after registering and/or resetting password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `UserController.php` , I hope email and passwords are the things you use for user signin.

```
public function userSignIn(Request $request)
{
      $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
      ]);

      if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']])){
        return redirect()->route('order'); 
      }
      return redirect()->back();
}
```

You must have a route for `order` in your `route.php` file.